# Different instances of A in B (Python)

Tags: python, class, instance

In a situation like this b1 and b2 both have the same instanse of A.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=1

class B:
    a=A()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

b1=B()
b2=B()
b1.a.var=2 #changing "var" in b1 would also change it in b2
print(b2.a.var) # prints 2
```

What should i do to have 2 different instances of A in B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `B` defined as it is, its attribute `a` belongs to the class itself, not each individual instance. You would need to do something like this:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
```

to get separate instances of `A` for every `B`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize it on a per-instance basis instead of at the class level like you have now:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
```

Answer (score 2):

You were using what amounts to a static variable. Try this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initialising `A()` as a static class variable when it is first parsed.
To have one instance of `A()` per instance of `B()` it should be in the `__init__` of `B()`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=1
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

b1=B()
b2=B()
b1.a.var=2 # changing "var" in b1 would not change it in b2
print(b2.a.var) # now prints 1
```

Comment: You don't need the `<code><pre>` to format code. Just indent everything with 4 spaces and all is well.